# how to insert a verify code HTML Standard Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

i have a product ,
 product infor was save in table ,
 and have a field verify_code,
i will create a string by md5 and insert to this field,
and i want send this verify_code to paypal then i can check response return from paypal
if verify_code == response verify_code will do next action
how i can do it with html standard paypal?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a hidden field named 'custom' in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Your_Verify_Code" />
```

You can check all the Html Variables that Paypal uses here:
[link text](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)